# Change value of global variable crash android

Tags: android, button, view, global-variables, variable-assignment

i have the class MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int mVariable= ((Constant)getApplicationContext()).variable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button count= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);


     count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){    
        public void onClick(View v) {    
            mVariable ++;
            tx.setText(" "+mVariable);

               ....
```

and the Constant class

```
        public class Constant extends Application {
        public int variable=0;

           }
```

and this doesn't work ..i declare Constant in Manifest.

```
         <application
                      ...
          android:name=".Constant"/>
```

I want to set value by onClick like this code and change the value of a global variable.. thanks

Comment: you can make your variable Static and then acces it Constant.variable++;

Comment: nice good luck for your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this variable as `Static` and access it in every other classes in your project like `Constant.variable` :

```
public class Constant extends Application {
        public static int variable = 0;

}
```

And

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ......
     tx.setText(" " + Constant.variable);
    .......

}
```

And now the `variable` is available throughout the whole project by `Constant.variable` and when you change the `variable`'s value, it will be applied to all classes.

I don't now what actually happened inyour project but above is just a suggestion to your problem.